# How to wait for information (currentUser) before componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a user profile page, when I refresh the page my redux store clears and then I have a fetch all the information again from the backend... but my profile page begins to mount before I get that information back.

I this function in my "loggedInRoutes.js". It will get the currentUser from the JWT token I have in localStorage, and save the userName and ID, etc, in my Redux Store

```
  componentDidMount(){
    if (localStorage.length===0){
     this.props.history.push('/')
    }else{
      this.props.dispatchCurrentUser()
    }
  }
```

It's in the top level of my routes, the switch statement with my route rendering is in the same page.

In my profile page. (I need to check if the currentUser is friends with the user who's profile I went to, that's why I need both infos from the start).

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchProfile(this.props.currentUser, this.props.match.params.userId)
    this.requestFriendshipFunction()
  }
```

This works if I already have the currentUser in my redux store, but if I do a page refresh while on the profile page, the componentDidMount in the profile page gets called before I have that information, even though I'm calling the "dispatchCurrentUser" in a more container/parent component "loggedInRoutes".

Saving the currentUser info in local storage seems like a bad idea, and I'm not sure where to go from here. 
Thank you.

Comment: Just don't render a components which needs to know about the user and display a placeholder or spinner while it fetching. Wrap that components with HOC or add a check to all of them.

Comment: Okay so if I have it display a loader while I wait for my redux store to populate, where in my profile page do I make the API call (this.props.fetchProfile) to the backend. I have it in componentWillReceiveProps but from what I've read that's not ideal.